# Java валидация кириллицы без регулярных выражений

Tags: java, spring, валидация

Делаю учебное приложение на Spring Boot, имитирующее работу городской библиотеки. Нужно провалидировать названия книг.

Например название "Лермонтов: повести и рассказы". Можно конечно составить регулярное выражение на такую строку, но возможно есть более универсальный подход к валидированию таких строк, состоящих из кириллицы и в которых есть знаки препинания?

Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Что именно вы хотите "провалидировать"?

Comment: Ну написал же вроде.. Названия книг, состоящие из кириллицы, в которые могут входить знаки препинания.

Comment: То есть вам надо проверить, что в строке не встречаются символы отличные от кириллицы?

Comment: Да, так. Но могут встречаться знаки препинания.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Регулярным выражением, пожалуй, проще было бы, но можно и без него:

```
String PUNCTUATION = "'!\"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~' ";

String s = "Лермонтов: повести и рассказы";

boolean b = s.chars()
             .mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
             .filter(c -> PUNCTUATION.indexOf(c) == -1)
             .map(Character.UnicodeBlock::of)
             .allMatch(i -> i.equals(Character.UnicodeBlock.CYRILLIC));
```

Comment: Спасибо. Кириллица с пунктуацией проходит, другие варианты нет.